# Elasticsearch - Mappings Not created

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to create a mapping for a certain type in elastic search using the Java client, bur for some reason the mapping is not applied when I check the index. My code looks like this:

```
    XContentBuilder settingsBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .startObject("analysis")
                            .startObject("analyzer")
                                .startObject("default")
                                    .field("type", "pattern")
                                    .field("pattern", " ")
                                    .field("lowercase", false)
                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject();


   XContentBuilder mappingBuilder = jsonBuilder()
                    .startObject()
                        .startObject(ELASTIC_PROFILE_TYPE)
                            .startObject("properties")
                                .startObject(ELASTIC_ALL_FIELD_BOOL)
                                    .field("type", "text")
                                    .field("similarity", "boolean")
                                .endObject()
                            .endObject()
                         .endObject()
                   .endObject();

    indices.prepareCreate(this.index)
                    .setSettings(settingsBuilder)
                    .addMapping(ELASTIC_PROFILE_TYPE, mappingBuilder)
                    .get();

    GetFieldMappingsResponse getFieldMappingsResponse = indices.prepareGetFieldMappings(this.index).setTypes(ELASTIC_PROFILE_TYPE).get();

    System.out.println(getFieldMappingsResponse.mappings());
```

But I get the following result:

```
{barista_test={}}
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you give the ES version which you are using?

Comment: I am using version 5.5